# Cheriton-Tarjan algorithm for MST

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

I am searching the Cheriton-Tarjan algorithm for weighted minimum spanning trees, with O(m*loglogn). But I was not able to find it anywhere. Can someone explain me the algorithm or tell me a link as where to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's "Tarjan" not "Trajan". That may be a reason why you've had trouble finding it.

Here's pseudocode for the algorithm, taken from [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zxSmHAoMiRUC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=cheriton-tarjan%20algorithm&source=bl&ots=LQWYqzK7bq&sig=mmKjYZ7pevW3vkPD1Xmg7GC5BOI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0AX4UsykO_Cp7AbWiICADg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=cheriton-tarjan%20algorithm&f=false) (Graphcs, Algorithms, and Optimization by William Kocay and Donald Kreher):

[image]